# C# Create an instance of a class from string

Tags: c#, reflection, instance

I am new in C# and I want to create an instance for **MyTestClass** in runtime. How can I do it ?

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public MyTestClass()
    {
        Value = 5;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I just want to create an instance of *MyTestClass* from string variable like

```
string classInstance = "MyTestClass"
```

I couldn't explain completely at first time, sorry for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "in runtime"?

Comment: `new MyTestClass()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new instance in runtime using **Activator** class. Like this;

```
var instance = (MyTestClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyTestClass));
```

Comment: Why suggest that rather than `MyTestClass myTestClass = new MyTestClass();`?

Comment: I think it might be a reflection thing

Comment: Because the question has been mentioned for "Reflection".

Comment: @Rainman You're not using reflection, in addition to having code that doesn't compile.

Comment: @information_interchange True, but if you already know the type at compile-time you don’t need reflection at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static I CreateInstance<I>() where I : class  
{  
    string assemblyPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\MyTestClass.exe";  

    Assembly assembly;  

    assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);  
    Type type = assembly.GetType("MyTestClass");  
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as I;  
}
```